# Update local cache (database data) in browser with websockets

Tags: caching, websocket

In a project I keep the most essential database data updated/cached in the browser, to reduce API get calls to the server as much as possible.

Whenever data is updated on the server it is pushed to each connected client via websockets.

Data is only shared between users created on the same client number, and data is therefore not broadcasted to all users like a chat or something similar. The data is only pushed to a few connected websockets.

If a user with the same session has multiple browser tabs open a new websocket connection is created in each browser tab, and each browser tab is identified by a random generated id (generated by the client and sent when the WS connection is created) like `b82ks95` on the server to keep track who is updating data.

If a user (same session) with 3 browser tabs opened (let's call the tabs `A`, `B` and `C`). If tab `A` is either creating/updating data on the server, the updates are only pushed to `B` and `C` via websockets. The cache in tab `A` is updated by the HTTP response.

The cached data on the client/browser is set in an object

```
const cached_data = {
  tableA: {...},
  tableB: {...}
};
```

Is there a better and more simple way of handling the cached data in the browser?